How to fill in a data frame with values from second?
I have a data frame with binary 1's and 0's, and I would like to fill in with a set of data from a second data frame
The real data frame has 1000s of lines, so would be good to have a fast way.
Some example data:
data <- data.frame(array(sample(c(0,1),25,replace=TRUE),dim=c(6,4)))
colnames(data) <- c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4")
size <- data.frame(array(c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4",13,16,14,12),dim=c(4,2)))

> data
  sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
1   1   1   1   0
2   0   0   1   0
3   1   1   0   0
4   0   1   0   1
5   0   0   1   0
6   0   0   0   0
> size
   X1 X2
1 sp1 13
2 sp2 16
3 sp3 14
4 sp4 12

I would like a dataframe that looks like this
    sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
1   13  16  14  0
2   0   0   14  0
3   13  16  0   0
4   0   16  0   12
5   0   0   14  0
6   0   0   0   0


Data
(changing size$X2 to numeric)
set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(array(sample(c(0,1),25,replace=TRUE),dim=c(6,4)))

colnames(data) <- c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4")

size <- data.frame(X1=c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4"), X2=c(13,16,14,12))

With sapply
data.frame(sapply(names(data), \(x)
  ifelse(data[x] == 1, size$X2[which(size$X1 == x)], 0)))
  sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
1   0   0   0  12
2  13   0   0   0
3   0  16   0   0
4   0  16  14   0
5  13   0  14   0
6   0   0  14   0


That works, great thanks!

You could do:
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~if_else(.x == 1,
                         as.numeric(size[size$X1 == cur_column(), 'X2']),
                         .x)))

Since you are using sampled data I‘m setting a seed:
set.seed(1)

which gives the following input and output:
  sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
1   0   0   0   1
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0
4   0   1   1   0
5   1   0   1   0
6   0   0   1   0


  sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
1   0   0   0  12
2  13   0   0   0
3   0  16   0   0
4   0  16  14   0
5  13   0  14   0
6   0   0  14   0

